# animal kingdom heiracrchy code not working as expected

Tags: java

I am currently working on a project whcih requires me to create animals, within this collection are birds and mammal classes, which both have tiger and lion clasees and eagle and parrot classes, however I cannot get my code to compile sucessfully, below is my code:

```
public abstract class Tiger extends Mammal
{
    public static void main(String args[]){

      Animal a = new Animal();
      Mammal m = new Mammal();
      tiger t = new Tiger();

      System.out.println(m instanceof Animal);
      System.out.println(t instanceof Mammal);
      System.out.println(t instanceof Animal);
   }

}
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `tiger t` should be `Tiger t`. Java is case sensitive (as are many, many other languages).

Comment: If the code doesn't compile, then presumably you've got an error. Always, always **always** include the error message in a question like this...

Comment: Try `Tiger t = new Tiger();` instead of `tiger t = new Tiger();`

Comment: keeps giving me the following error: constructor Animal in class Animal cannot be Applied to given types; required: java.lang.string,java.lang.string,Mlyzoo found no arguments, reason: actual and formal argument lsits differ in length

Comment: So on top of the problems that others have pointed out - you're trying to invoke a constructor that doesn't exist. The error message is telling you that it's expecting a call to `Animal(String, String, Mlyzoo)` (Myzoo?), but got `Animal()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove word abstract from tiger.
2. Override all abstract methods from super classes (mamal and animal).

Comment: You didn't see anything wrong with `tiger t = new Tiger();`?

Comment: I did, but people already commented about that, so why duplicate? Instead I added solution to possibly other reasons of problem.

Comment: It makes your answer incomplete.

Comment: Probably you are right. Sometimes I wish I could simply comment under the question, as some questions do not need a proper answer, but a bunch of tips are enough.

Comment: +1, you'll get 50 rep for commenting soon enough! Edit: just did!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate an abstract class. Remove the abstract keyword from the class declaration. Also, your class name and object declaration do not match. Capitalize the T in the object declaration.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the `abstract` modifier from the `Tiger` class.
2. Java is case sensitive. tiger != Tiger. Just write it with an capital T. (Even the code highlighting on SO shows what is wrong. `tiger` is not colored blue.)